# Dundas Chart in User Control

Tags: asp.net, dundas

I have a dundas chart with ajax zooming and scrolling enable. 
It works fine in a webform page. But once I put in a user control and called it from another page I get this error -

the target 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uc2$chartVisits' for the callback could not be found or did not implement ICallbackEventHandler.

-when I try to use the zoom and scroll functionality.

What can I do to resolve this problem.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this error when dynamically adding controls that use AJAX. Make sure you're adding any controls in the `OnInit` method, or during the `Page_Init` event. That has solved this problem for me in the past.