# The target 'myCTL$mSnap5$zj4kzq2zcmbfipjchti4ylg_1656564000_Chart_5' for the callback could not befound or did not implement ICallbackEventHandler

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asynchronous, charts

I have a Live chart page that contains multiple Dundas charts and the page is refreshed every few minutes, depending on the setting. Normally, it runs fine. But when the chart is run 24x7, only sometimes the following error occurs and the further refreshing of the page/charts fails.

> **The target 'myCTL$mSnap5$zj4kzq2zcmbfipjchti4ylg_1656564000_Chart_5' for the callback could not befound or did not implement
>   ICallbackEventHandler**

I am creating the chart control in page_load event. I have gone through many links that has addressed this issue.

[Dundas Chart in User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956327/dundas-chart-in-user-control)

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q291476/icallbackeventhandler-exception-when-charts-are-loaded-dynamically

Placing the chart control creation logic in Page_Init event did not do the trick for me. Another solution suggested in the below link is to implement ICallbackEventHandler. This requires lot of changes to the logic that I want to avoid as it is an old and large page that runs fine most of the time.

https://forums.asp.net/t/953036.aspx

Below is the Page_Load event code and the chart's callback event handler.

```
  try
        {
            //check if user has the right to start
        if (!Page.IsCallback && !Page.IsPostBack &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[QLR.QC.ParamMenuKey]) ||
             !QLR.Rights.DB.UserHasRightsToStart(UserID, Request.QueryString[QLR.QC.ParamMenuKey])))
        {
            //user (rolid) has not the right to start
            RealtimeCharts_Panel.Visible = false;
            NoRights_Panel.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!cbFavLoad.IsCallback &&
                !cbFavAdd.IsCallback)
            {
                QLR.LiveCharts.Basics.CreateDockingContainers(
                            DockingContainers_Row,
                            NoOfDockingContainers,
                            ref myDockingContainers);

                string AllSyncMethods = string.Empty;
                string AllTimerEventRefs = string.Empty;
                string AllChartStopEventRefs = string.Empty;
                string AllResetEventRefs = string.Empty;
                string AllVisiblePointsChangedEventRefs = string.Empty;

                SnapOrderTable_Preset.InnerHtml = "<script language=\"javascript\">";

                sb.Append("START - FOR LOOP" + " " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < NoOfCharts; i++)
                {
                    //load usercontrol with snap and chart
                    Control ChartBaseCtl = (Control)LoadControl("LC02_LiveChartControl.ascx");
                    ChartBaseCtl.ID = "myCTL" + i.ToString();
                    ((LC02_LiveChartControl)ChartBaseCtl).ChartNo = i;
                    ((LC02_LiveChartControl)ChartBaseCtl).ActLanguage = ActLanguage;
                    ((LC02_LiveChartControl)ChartBaseCtl).StaticSnapsCount = StaticSnapsCount;

                    //BEGIN - set some snap basics
                    ComponentArt.Web.UI.Snap tSnap =
                        (ComponentArt.Web.UI.Snap)QLR.CF.FindControlRecursive(ChartBaseCtl, "Snap1");
                    tSnap.ID = "mSnap" + i.ToString();
                    tSnap.DockingContainers = myDockingContainers;
                    //tSnap.MinimizeDirectionElement = Menu1.ClientObjectId + "_0";

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FAVID_REQUESTED.Value) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SnapContainersList_Hidden.Value) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SnapDockingIndexList_Hidden.Value))
                    {
                        string[] SnapContainers = SnapContainersList_Hidden.Value.Split(';');
                        string[] SnapIndexes = SnapDockingIndexList_Hidden.Value.Split(';');

                        if (i < SnapContainers.Length)
                        {
                            //Response.Write("<br>" + i.ToString() + ":" + SnapContainers[i] + "#" + SnapIndexes[i]);
                            //check if requested SnapContainer is available
                            TableCell myDockC = (TableCell)QLR.CF.FindControlRecursive(Page, SnapContainers[i]);
                            if (myDockC != null)
                            {
                                //container (TableCell) is available
                                tSnap.CurrentDockingContainer = SnapContainers[i];

                                if (SnapIndexes.Length == NoOfCharts)
                                { tSnap.CurrentDockingIndex = Convert.ToInt32(SnapIndexes[i]); }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //ChartColumn number to dock Snap
                                tSnap.CurrentDockingContainer = "ChartColumn" + (i % NoOfDockingContainers).ToString();

                                //calculate current docking index for snap
                                tSnap.CurrentDockingIndex = Convert.ToInt32(i / NoOfDockingContainers);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //ChartColumn number to dock Snap
                            tSnap.CurrentDockingContainer = "ChartColumn" + (i % NoOfDockingContainers).ToString();

                            //set docking index for snap to zero (=undefined)
                            tSnap.CurrentDockingIndex = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //ChartColumn number to dock Snap
                        tSnap.CurrentDockingContainer = "ChartColumn" + (i % NoOfDockingContainers).ToString();

                        //calculate current docking index for snap
                        tSnap.CurrentDockingIndex = Convert.ToInt32(i / NoOfDockingContainers);
                    }

                    //SnapHeaderTable width
                    Table SnapHeaderTable = (Table)tSnap.FindControl("SnapHeaderTable");
                    SnapHeaderTable.Width = Convert.ToInt32(ChartWidth.SelectedValue);
                    Table SnapHeaderCollapsedTable = (Table)tSnap.FindControl("SnapHeaderCollapsedTable");
                    SnapHeaderCollapsedTable.Width = Convert.ToInt32(ChartWidth.SelectedValue);
                    //END - set some snap basics

                    //BEGIN - set some chart basics
                    Dundas.Charting.WebControl.Chart tChart =
                        (Dundas.Charting.WebControl.Chart)QLR.CF.FindControlRecursive(ChartBaseCtl, "Chart1");
                    tChart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.White;
                    tChart.ID = UniqueSessionID + "_Chart_" + i.ToString();
                    tChart.Width = Convert.ToInt32(ChartWidth.SelectedValue);
                    tChart.Height = Convert.ToInt32(ChartHeight.SelectedValue);
                    tChart.Callback += new CommandEventHandler(this.AllCharts_Callback);
                    tChart.CallbackComplete += new CommandEventHandler(this.AllCharts_CallbackComplete);
                    tChart.AxisViewChanged += new ViewEventHandler(this.Chart_AxisViewChanged);
                    tChart.ChartScroll += new Chart.ChartScrollEventHandler(Chart_ChartScroll);
                    //END - set some chart basics

                    //add current control with snap and chart to panel
                    DynamicSnaps_Panel.Controls.Add(ChartBaseCtl);

                    //add menu entry for snap
                    ComponentArt.Web.UI.MenuItem newItem = new ComponentArt.Web.UI.MenuItem();
                    int MenuItemIndex = StaticSnapsCount + i;
                    newItem.Text = "Chart" + (i + 1).ToString();
                    newItem.ToolTip = "Chart" + (i + 1).ToString();
                    //newItem.Text = tSnap.ClientObjectId;
                    newItem.ClientSideCommand = "ToggleSnapMinimize(" + tSnap.ClientObjectId + ", " + MenuItemIndex.ToString() + ");";
                    Menu1.Items[0].Items.Add(newItem);

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        //set NoOfSeries
                        NoOfSeries = tChart.Series.Count;

                        //for all chart series select current color (colorpicker)
                        for (int co = 0; co < NoOfSeries; co++)
                        {
                            //get reference to ColorPicker
                            QLR.UIComponents.ColorPicker myColorPicker =
                                (QLR.UIComponents.ColorPicker)QLR.CF.FindControlRecursive(Page, "ColorPicker" + co.ToString());

                            myColorPicker.SelectedHexValue = tChart.Series[co].Color.ToString();
                            if (tChart.Series[co].Color.ToString().IndexOf("#") == -1)
                            {
                                //convert color string (e.g. GRAY) to HEX
                                myColorPicker.SelectedHexValue = "#" +
                                    QLR.CF.ColorToHex(tChart.Series[co].Color);
                            }
                        }

                        //set color of scalebreakline to color from usercontrol
                        ColorPickerScaleBreakLine.SelectedHexValue = "#" +
                            QLR.CF.ColorToHex(tChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.LineColor);

                        //replace chart colors from usercontrol with colors form PARAMSET
                        //if available
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SeriesColorsSelected_Hidden.Value))
                        {
                            string[] SeriesColors = SeriesColorsSelected_Hidden.Value.Split(';');
                            for (int co = 0; co < SeriesColors.Length; co++)
                            {
                                //get reference to ColorPicker
                                QLR.UIComponents.ColorPicker myColorPicker =
                                    (QLR.UIComponents.ColorPicker)QLR.CF.FindControlRecursive(Page, "ColorPicker" + co.ToString());

                                myColorPicker.SelectedHexValue = "#" + SeriesColors[co];
                            }
                        }

                        //replace scalebreaklinecolor from usercontrol with color from PARAMSET
                        //if available (e.g. ff00ff)
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ScaleBreakLineColor_Hidden.Value))
                        {
                            ColorPickerScaleBreakLine.SelectedHexValue = "#" +
                                ScaleBreakLineColor_Hidden.Value;
                        }
                    }

                    //build ChartCallback Argumentstring by JS-Function "getChartCallbackArguments"
                    string CallbackArguments = "'+ getChartCallbackArguments(" + i.ToString() + ") +'";

                    AllSyncMethods +=
                        "/*alert('GetCallbackAsyncMethodReference');*/ if (!isWhitespace(CallbackChartParamsArray[" + i.ToString() + "]) && CallbackChartParamsArray[" + i.ToString() + "]!=undefined) " +
                        "{ CBStatusArray[" + i.ToString() + "]='1';" +
                        tChart.CallbackManager.GetCallbackAsyncMethodReference("Timer", CallbackArguments) +
                        " }";

                    AllTimerEventRefs +=
                        "if (!isWhitespace(CallbackChartParamsArray[" + i.ToString() + "]) && CallbackChartParamsArray[" + i.ToString() + "]!=undefined) " +
                        "{ CBStatusArray[" + i.ToString() + "]='1';" +
                        tChart.CallbackManager.GetCallbackEventReference("Timer", CallbackArguments) +
                        " }";

                    AllChartStopEventRefs +=
                        "if (!isWhitespace(CallbackChartParamsArray[" + i.ToString() + "]) && CallbackChartParamsArray[" + i.ToString() + "]!=undefined) " +
                        "{ CBStatusArray[" + i.ToString() + "]='1';" +
                        tChart.CallbackManager.GetCallbackAsyncMethodReference("ChartStop", CallbackArguments) +
                        " }";

                    AllResetEventRefs +=
                        "if (ChartMeasPointsCountArray[" + i.ToString() + "] > 0)" +
                        "{ CBStatusArray[" + i.ToString() + "]='1';" +
                        tChart.CallbackManager.GetCallbackAsyncMethodReference("ChartReset", CallbackArguments) +
                        " }";

                    AllVisiblePointsChangedEventRefs +=
                        "if (!isWhitespace(CallbackChartParamsArray[" + i.ToString() + "]) " +
                        " && CallbackChartParamsArray[" + i.ToString() + "]!=undefined " +
                        " && ChartMeasPointsCountArray[" + i.ToString() + "]!='0')" +
                        "{ CBStatusArray[" + i.ToString() + "]='1';" +
                        tChart.CallbackManager.GetCallbackAsyncMethodReference("VisiblePointsChanged", CallbackArguments) +
                        " }";

                    //Add Snap container and index to Snap Order Table
                    SnapOrderTable_Preset.InnerHtml += "setSnapOrderItem('" + tSnap.ClientID + "','" + tSnap.CurrentDockingContainer + "'," + tSnap.CurrentDockingIndex + ");";
                }//over all charts

                SnapOrderTable_Preset.InnerHtml += "</script>";

                sb.Append("END - FOR LOOP" + " " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine();

                AllSyncMethods += "ShowCBStatus();";

                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    typeof(string),
                    "DoAllAsyncs",
                    "function DoAllAsyncs()" +
                    "{ /*alert('DoAllAsyncs invoked!'); */" + AllSyncMethods + " }",
                    true);

                sb.Append("RegisterClientScriptBlock - DoAllAsyncs" + " " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine();

                string ZoomedChartCallbackArguments =
                    "'+ zoomedChartNo +'" +
                    "#" + "'+ bVisRunning +'" +
                    "#" + "'+ bResetZoomScroll +'";

                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    typeof(string),
                    "UpdateZoomedChart",
                    "function UpdateZoomedChart(ChartNo, bVisRunning, bResetZoomScroll) {" +
                    "  var zoomedChartNo=document.getElementById('" + ZoomedChartNo.ClientID + "').value;" +
                    "  if(zoomedChartNo==ChartNo) {" +
                    "    document.getElementById('CBZoomedStatus').value='1';" +
                    "    ShowCBZoomedStatus();" +
                         ZoomedChart.CallbackManager.GetCallbackAsyncMethodReference("ZOOM", ZoomedChartCallbackArguments) +
                    "  }" +
                    "}",
                    true);

                sb.Append("RegisterClientScriptBlock - UpdateZoomedChart" + " " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine();

                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    typeof(string),
                    "DoAllTimerEvents",
                    "function DoAllTimerEvents()" +
                    "{ " + AllTimerEventRefs + " }",
                    true);

                sb.Append("RegisterClientScriptBlock - DoAllTimerEvents" + " " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine();

                SettingsOK_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleSettings()");
                ColorSettingsOK_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleSettings()");
                DebugSettingsOK_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleSettings()");
                MeasSettingsOK_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleMeasSettings()");

                //STOP
                string StopString =
                    "alert('" + QLR.CF.TxGet("LC02_STOP_MESSAGE", ActLanguage) + "');" +
                    "document.getElementById('" + STOP_Requested_Hidden.ClientID + "').value='1';" +
                    "if(SettingsDialog.get_isShowing()) { StartDDLTimerHide(); SettingsDialog.Close(); }" +
                    "if(MeasSettingsDialog.get_isShowing()) { StartDDLTimerHide(); MeasSettingsDialog.Close(); }" +
                    "if(ChartZoomDialog.get_isShowing()) { ChartZoomDialog.Close(); }" +
                    "if(window.myTimer) { window.clearTimeout(window.myTimer); }" +
                    AllChartStopEventRefs +
                    "EnableAllToolbarItems();";

                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    typeof(string),
                    "StopOnlineMonitoring",
                    "function StopOnlineMonitoring() " +
                    "{ " + StopString + " }" + QLR.QC.CRLF,
                    true);

                //RESET
                string ResetString =
                    "alert('" + QLR.CF.TxGet("LC02_RESET_MESSAGE", ActLanguage) + "');" +
                    "if(window.myTimer) { window.clearTimeout(window.myTimer); }" +
                    "if(SettingsDialog.get_isShowing()) { StartDDLTimerHide(); SettingsDialog.Close(); }" +
                    "if(MeasSettingsDialog.get_isShowing()) { StartDDLTimerHide(); MeasSettingsDialog.Close(); }" +
                    "if(ChartZoomDialog.get_isShowing()) { ChartZoomDialog.Close(); }" +
                    "document.getElementById('" + ZoomedChartNo.ClientID + "').value='-1';" +
                    AllResetEventRefs +
                    "ResetAllArrays();" +
                    "EnableAllToolbarItems();";

                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    typeof(string),
                    "ResetOnlineMonitoring",
                    "function ResetOnlineMonitoring() " +
                    "{ " + ResetString + " }" + QLR.QC.CRLF,
                    true);

                //only do async call to change charts if timer is not active!
                //if timer is active changed "visible points" will work on next timer run
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    typeof(string),
                    "VisiblePointsChanged",
                    "function VisiblePointsChanged() " +
                    "{ " + AllVisiblePointsChangedEventRefs + " }" + QLR.QC.CRLF,
                    true);
            }//!cbFavLoad && !cbFavAdd

            //--> = Chart1_Callback if VisiblePoints was changed ...
            VisiblePoints.Attributes.Add("onchange", "VisiblePointsChanged()");

            AJAX_DDL_UNITTYPE.Attributes.Add("onchange", "UnittypeChanged()");
            AJAX_DDL_AREA.Attributes.Add("onchange", "AreaChanged()");

            AJAX_DDL_TESTSTATUS.Attributes.Add("onchange", "TeststatusChanged()");
            AJAX_DDL_TESTSTATUSGROUP.Attributes.Add("onchange", "TeststatusGroupChanged()");

        }//user has rights to start
    }//try

      /// <summary>
      /// Chart Callback event handler.
      /// </summary>
     protected void AllCharts_Callback(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
     {
          //leave snap-header-labels as is if "RESET" is requested
        if (e.CommandName != "ChartReset")
        {
             //Code
        }

         //Handle Timer callback command
         if (e.CommandName == "Timer")
         {
             //Code
         }
      }
```

### **LC02_LiveChartControl.ascx Code**

```
            <%@ Control ClassName="LC02_LiveChartControl" Language="C#" CodeFile="LC02_LiveChartControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="LC02_LiveChartControl" %>
            <%@ Register TagPrefix="ComponentArt" Namespace="ComponentArt.Web.UI" Assembly="ComponentArt.Web.UI" %>
            <!-- BEGIN - CHART -->
            <ComponentArt:Snap 
              id="Snap1"
              DockingContainers="ChartColumn0"
              CurrentDockingContainer="ChartColumn0"
              CurrentDockingIndex="0"
              CollapseDuration="300"
              ExpandDuration="300"
              DraggingStyle="GhostCopy"
              DockingStyle="TransparentRectangle"
              MinimizeDuration="450"
              MinimizeSlide="Linear"
              MustBeDocked="True"
              IsCollapsed="false"
              runat="server">
            <Header>
             </Header>
            <Content>
                <asp:Panel ID="Chart_Panel" runat="server">
                <DCWC:CHART id="Chart1" CallbackStateContent="All" ImageType="Png" Height="150" Width="350" ImageUrl="~/ChartX/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" BackColor="white" Palette="Dundas" BorderLineStyle="Solid" BackGradientEndColor="White" BackGradientType="TopBottom" BorderLineWidth="1" BorderLineColor="gray" runat="server">
                    <Legends>
                        <dcwc:Legend Enabled="False" Docking="Bottom" Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Row" AutoFitText="False" BorderColor="Gray" Name="Default" BackColor="Transparent" Font="Arial, 10px" TitleFont="Arial, 12px, style=Bold"></dcwc:Legend>
                    </Legends>
                    <Titles>
                        <DCWC:Title Docking="Top" DockOffset="-2" Alignment="TopCenter" BackColor="Transparent" Font="Arial, 9px, style=Bold"></DCWC:Title>
                    </Titles>
                    <Series>
                        <dcwc:Series LegendText="Meas" XValueType="Double" YValueType="Double" Name="MEAS" Color="Gray" ChartType="Line" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="1"></dcwc:Series>
                        <dcwc:Series LegendText="UCL" XValueType="Double" YValueType="Double" Name="UCL" Color="#ff0000" ChartType="Line" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="2"></dcwc:Series>
                        <dcwc:Series LegendText="LCL" XValueType="Double" YValueType="Double" Name="LCL" Color="#ff0000" ChartType="Line" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="2"></dcwc:Series>
                        <dcwc:Series LegendText="XQ" XValueType="Double" YValueType="Double" Name="MEAN" Color="Blue" ChartType="Line" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="1"></dcwc:Series>
                        <dcwc:Series LegendText="+3s" XValueType="Double" YValueType="Double" Name="PLUS3S" Color="Blue" BorderStyle="Dash" ChartType="Line" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="1"></dcwc:Series>
                        <dcwc:Series LegendText="-3s" ShowInLegend="false" XValueType="Double" YValueType="Double" Name="MINUS3S" Color="Blue" BorderStyle="Dash" ChartType="Line" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="1"></dcwc:Series>
                        <dcwc:Series Enabled="false" LegendText="RANGE" XValueType="Double" YValueType="Double" Name="RANGE" Color="Gray" ChartType="Line" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="1"></dcwc:Series>
                        <dcwc:Series Enabled="false" LegendText="N_RANGE" XValueType="Double" YValueType="Double" Name="N_RANGE" Color="Blue" ChartType="Line" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="1"></dcwc:Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <dcwc:ChartArea Name="Default" BackColor="White">
                            <Position X="2" Y="10" Width="95" Height="82"></Position>
                            <InnerPlotPosition Auto="false" Width="90" Height="84" X="8" Y="0" />
                            <CursorX UserEnabled="false" UserSelection="false" />
                            <CursorY UserEnabled="false" UserSelection="false" />
                            <AxisX LabelsAutoFit="False" LineColor="gray" Margin="False" StartFromZero="True">
                                <LabelStyle Font="Arial, 9px" FontColor="Gray" ShowEndLabels="True" FontAngle="-90"></LabelStyle>
                                <MajorGrid LineColor="gray" />
                                <MajorTickMark LineColor="gray" />
                                <MinorTickMark LineColor="gray" Enabled="true" Interval="Auto" />
                                <ScrollBar Size="6" Enabled="true" />
                            </AxisX>
                            <AxisY LabelsAutoFit="False" LineColor="gray" StartFromZero="False" TitleFont="Arial, 9px" TitleColor="Black">
                                <LabelStyle Font="Arial, 9px" FontColor="Gray" Interval="Auto" IntervalOffset="Auto" IntervalOffsetType="Auto" IntervalType="Auto"></LabelStyle>
                                <MajorGrid LineColor="gray" Interval="Auto" IntervalOffset="Auto" IntervalOffsetType="Auto" IntervalType="Auto"></MajorGrid>
                                <MajorTickMark LineColor="gray" Interval="Auto" IntervalOffset="Auto" IntervalOffsetType="Auto" IntervalType="Auto" />
                                <MinorTickMark LineColor="gray" Enabled="true" Interval="Auto" />
                                <ScrollBar Size="6" Enabled="true" />
                                <ScaleBreakStyle LineColor="#ff00ff" LineStyle="Solid" LineWidth="1" Spacing="2" BreakLineType="Straight" MaxNumberOfBreaks="1" StartFromZero="False" CollapsibleSpaceThreshold="75" Enabled="false" />
                            </AxisY>
                        </dcwc:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                    <BorderSkin SkinStyle="None" PageColor="#D1D1D1" />
                </DCWC:CHART>
                </asp:Panel>
            </Content>
            <Footer>
            <div style="margin-top:5px"></div>
            </Footer>
            <ClientEvents>
                <SnapDock EventHandler="Snap_onSnapDock" />
            </ClientEvents>
            </ComponentArt:Snap>
```

It is a huge page and has large code. I have tried to include here as much as possible. Could anyone please help.Thanks

Comment: Charts refresh every minute through asynchronous callback. By using console.log and Chrome Developer Tools, I have found out the following information of client side. XmlHttpRequest.send() is taking more time (may be due to some issue on server side) and hence readyState change is delayed. In such case, the next minute refresh starts, at that point if the calback result of a chart of a previous refresh returns (delayed due to some issue on server side) , this error occurs saying the target (chart that initiated the callback) could not be found. Anyone having more idea about this?